# ¿Debo, o no, incluir la carpeta node_modules dentro de las carpetas que GIT debe ignorar?

Tags: nodejs, git, npm, vscode

Parto contextualizando. [Este repositorio de GitHub que hice](https://github.com/cealcuadrado/foopackage), tiene solamente un archivo subido a él, un archivo `package.json`, que lo saqué de una plantilla propia de aplicación web que uso. Esa aplicación usa diversas herramientas y frameworks, entre ellas AngularJS, Bootstrap 3, SASS, etc., y usa Grunt como automatizador.

Los dos aspectos relevantes para este escenario que planteo, son que:

1. Se usa **NPM** como gestor de paquetes.
2. En el repositorio no hay un archivo `.gitignore`, es decir, **no hay archivo para especificar qué archivos/carpetas son los que GIT debe ignorar**. Es crucial para lo que viene más adelante.

El contenido del archivo `package.json`, [como aparece en el repositorio](https://github.com/cealcuadrado/foopackage/blob/master/package.json), es el siguiente:

```
{
  "name": "miproyecto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.4",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-htmlhint": "^0.9.13",
    "grunt-stylelint": "^0.12.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^5.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^11.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.2",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.22",
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "angular-animate": "^1.7.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Una vez clonado el repositorio, en Visual Studio Code (que es el editor que uso), abro una terminal, y luego ejecuto `npm install` para instalar las dependencias.

Cuando termina la instalación de las dependencias, y la generación de la carpeta `node_modules`, me llama la atención que, desde la extensión de Git de VSC (que la tengo instalada), me sale la siguiente notificación (la pongo en imagen y en texto):

> The git repository at '[carpeta local donde tengo la copia en local de mi repositorio]' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled. Would you like to add 'node_modules' to .gitignore?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que hace referencia al volumen de cambios activos que estaban ocurriendo, y por ello me sugiere si quiero incluir la carpeta `node_modules` en un archivo `.gitignore`, que hasta este momento, no lo tenía creado.

Considerando el volumen de cambios descrito para GIT, y el peso en disco duro que implican las dependencias instaladas, es que quiero preguntar:

1. ¿Debo, o no, incluir la carpeta `node_modules`, dentro de las carpetas que GIT debe ignorar?
2. Fuera de los aspectos de volúmen y peso, ¿Qué ventajas y desventajas se me presentan al hacerlo, o al no hacerlo?

Comment: La dependencias en la carpeta node_modules pueden ser inmensas, montones  de archivos que sería una locura subir al repositorio. Es suficiente subir el package.json y cualquiera que se descargue el proyecto solo tienen que hacer un `npm install` como has hecho tú y tendrá los paquetes necesarios

Comment: @blonfu Te pongo lo que me resultó de probarlo en local: Solo por instalar las dependencias del proyecto mostrado, en la carpeta `node_modules` se generaron 450 carpetas, aprox. unos 75 MB. Entiendo lo que dices, de modo de no generarle dramas a la persona con la que eventualmente voy a trabajar con mi repositorio. Lo pregunto porque estoy estableciendo ambientes formales de trabajo en local, y es primera vez que veo esa notificación.

Comment: No debes agregar los `node_modules` a tu repositorio ya que son bibliotecas de código externas administradas por terceros, si los agregas no sólo estarás siguiendo tus cambios sino los cambios que tengan estos archivos en caso de alguna actualización de su propietario. Estos módulos y sus versiones específicas están ya descritos en el package.json, por eso es que cualquiera en posesión de ese archivo podrá reconstruir tu proyecto sin problemas. Dale una leída a: https://julie.io/writing/javascript-node-modules/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta es simple: **NO**.

El archivo `node_modules` se reconstruye al ejecutar `npm install`, por lo tanto, solo debes controlar el archivo con las instrucciones para reconstruirlo, esto es, el archivo `packages.json`.

En general, no se controlan ni los resultados de la compilación ni los módulos que forman parte de las dependencias cuando existe un gestor de paquetes para el proyecto, *solo se controla el archivo que indica estas dependencias*.

Lo mismo pasa con Python y `pip`, Ruby y RubyGems, Go, Haskell y `cabal`, etc.

Comment: Tambien es importante controlar el archivo `package.lock`, para que en todos tus proyectos tengas exactamente la misa version. y asi evitar errores inesperados por pequenas diferencias en la version ya que el archivo `package.json` solo contiene un patron de version y no la version exacta.

Comment: pequena observacion, el archivo es `package.json`.
Muy buena respuesta