# Cuando subo un proyecto de VueCli a github no me sube la carpeta node_modules

Tags: javascript, nodejs, git, github, vuejs

Tengo un problema con github, soy practicamente nuevo en esto, estoy tratando de subir un proyecto de VueJs y cuando lo logro subir, al ver mi repositorio no aparece mi carpeta node_modules, pero todas las demas si como se ve en esta imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Seguramente está incluída en el archivo .gitignore para que así sea. Pero nota que no incluir esa carpeta en tu repositorio es lo recomendado.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309051/debo-o-no-incluir-la-carpeta-node-modules-dentro-de-las-carpetas-que-git-debe

Comment: No debería afectar siempre y cuando lo que subes a github tenga un package.json con eso basta para que en local quien se baje tu proyecto haga npm install y baje todas las dependencias necesarias

Comment: Entiendo, ahora mismo estoy ejecutando el comando npm install, no sabia que no era recomendado subir la carpeta node_modules, muchas gracias, son geniales!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Debo, o no, incluir la carpeta node\_modules dentro de las carpetas que GIT debe ignorar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309051/debo-o-no-incluir-la-carpeta-node-modules-dentro-de-las-carpetas-que-git-debe)

Answer (score 0):

Soy bastante nuevo en esto, pero solo bastaba que cuando baje mi repositorio ejecute el comando "npm install", el cual comenzaria a descargar lo que compone node_modules